# How do you specify the microsoft graph api login endpoint to be tenant-specific

Tags: ruby-on-rails, microsoft-graph-api, endpoint

I am developing an application which uses the microsoft graph api to pull data and authenticate users. We set the `SignInAudience` to `AzureADMyOrg` and we recieve: AADSTS50194: Application (...) is not configured as a multi-tenant application. Usage of the /common endpoint is not supported for such applications created after '10/15/2018'. Use a tenant-specific endpoint or configure the application to be multi-tenant.

In my eyes this means i need to use their organizations endpoint but in ruby on rails we do the following when we sign in users:

```
def sign_in
  redirect_to '/auth/microsoft_graph_auth'
end
```

I'm not really sure where or how i would specify the login endpoint to not use the /common one, as i can't seem to find it in my code or on the Azure AD portal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By following a from-scratch guide on how to set up an Azure AD authentication app i realized that i had in fact specified the login endpoint, found in `./lib/microsoft_graph_auth.rb`, where i simply changed

```
#/lib/microsoft_graph_auth.rb

    # Configure the Azure v2 endpoints
      option  :client_options,
              site: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
              authorize_url: '/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
              token_url: '/common/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```

to

```
#/lib/microsoft_graph_auth.rb

    # Configure the Azure v2 endpoints
      option  :client_options,
              site: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com',
              authorize_url: '/<tenant name>/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
              token_url: '/<tenant name>/oauth2/v2.0/token'
```